# I was making a program to display odd numbers from 1 to 100 using loops

Tags: java, loops, bluej

I am a begineer in java programming.
I was making a program to display odd numbers from 1 to 100 using loops. But that program when executed displays the odd number from 7 to 100 please help me to rectify that program.
The program.....

```
public class oddnumbers1to100
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for(int a=1;a<=100;a+=2) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: Ok i will try uninstalling compiler

Comment: Are you sure about what you're seeing? Maybe it is just your console, which has a very low buffer and starts "removing" the first lines, when it reaches the number 95. What do you see, then you use `System.out.print(a + " ");` instead?

Comment: Yes it displays odd numbers from 7 to 100. Wait i m uninstalling the compiler

Comment: Note : Uninstall your compiler/jvm, this is working, check whole output in the console.

I was compile this program working perfectly, just check you saved same program and compile same or other program.

Comment: Got the answer.

Comment: It worked after i did unlimited buffering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected the issue is the console you're using, in fact the console integrated in BlueJ, your IDE.

You can do two things to get the full output:

- List numbers horizontally:

  ```
  for (int a = 1; a <= 100; a+=2)
      System.out.print(a + " ");
  ```
- Or change the buffer setting of your console:

  - Click on "View" and then "Show Terminal" in the main menu (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
  - Then click on "Options" and select "Unlimited buffering"

Uninstalling the compiler or the IDE (as suggested in the comments) won't help you here, since it is not a problem of your program or your compiler.